# How can I send html.TextBox value with Url.Action to controller action method input argument?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I'm looking for a very simple way (without JS?).

So - I have the "CartController" which contains the following function:

```
public ActionResult AddToCart(Products prod, int amount)
```

So I want to keep the input of so-called @Html.TextBox and send it to the "AddToCart" as an input (using @Url.Action).

So here is my bad solution for this:

```
@Html.TextBox("Amount", new { @class = "form-control" })
@Url.Action("AddToCart", "Cart", product, "Amount")
```

Well, obviously it is a bad try...
Is there any simple way to solve it?

Comment: Use a form submit if you do not like to use JS. How are you currently sending the `Products` object data ?

Comment: Well, sending the 'Products' Data is simple because it is property of my Cart-Model, while "amount" is not.

Comment: Not following your prev comment. Are you doing a form submit ? If yes, add the amount input element to the form and it will work.

Comment: I'm not sure how to use it... would you mind to check it / fix it? https://pastebin.com/jcZKfzXX

Comment: why not using post method?